# Is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on a custom control a bad practice?

Tags: c#, patterns-and-practices, wpf

Imagine a `Control` is being created.

It has some `DependencyProperties` and there are some properties which depend on the `DependencyProperties`, but doesn't need to be seen or updated from the outside.

---

**For example**: `Foo` is a `DependencyProperty` (that can be both read and write from the outside) and `Bar` is a common property that will be updated when (*and only when*) `Foo` changes.

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    private static DependencyProperty FooProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Foo", 
                                    typeof(int), 
                                    typeof(MyControl), 
                                    new PropertyMetadata(FooChanged));

    private static void FooChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyControl changedObject = d as MyControl;

        changedObject.Bar++;
    }

    // The dependency property
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    // The property that is changed (only) when the dependency property changes
    public int Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

However, `Bar`'s value is displayed in the screen (a `Binding` is established in the control's template). But since `Bar` is **not** a `DependencyProperty` no notification is sent to say that it's value has changed.

I see two options to solve this issue (but I'm open to suggestions).

1. Make my `Control` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

or

2. Make `Bar` a readonly `DependencyProperty`

---

**What are the pros and cons of each approach? How should I proceed?**

Is it a bad practice to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on a `Control`?

**@EDIT**

This questions was raised when I was creating a control that filters and displays a collection of games.

The data of this collection is "constant" (the games are loaded with the app and doesn't change to the end of the execution). However, the user can apply filters to this collection (for example, only displaying games that are in English)

As you can imagine, the filters are the `Dependency Properties`, while the collection of games is a simple property, that I wasn't sure if I should turn into a ´DependencyProperty´ (since it would always be the same, only filtered according to the `ComboBoxes`)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12466216.  `INotifyPropertyChanged` is typically implemented in the ViewModel, not the View.

Comment: two answers here, one says do INotifyProperty changed, the other make it a DependencyProperty :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480366/how-to-raise-property-changed-events-on-a-dependency-property

Comment: I think the answer is WPF still isn't completely sure what its doing

Comment: @appayipyip too little for a proper answer but I'd say...it depends on what `bar` and `foo` are. If you want to expose a calculated property which, by case, will be binded and displayed then go with a `DependencyProperty` (think for example about `ActualWidth`). The point is that the property is not intended for visualization. If, instead, it's something that belongs only to visualization then it definitely must stay in the ViewModel (and yes, it's a bad practice to put it in the control).

Comment: Questions arise when it's intended for visualization but it's used only inside the reusable `Control`...where to put it? If in ViewModel you then put a strong requirement on the data context associated with the control. If that's the case then you may introduce a local _private_ ViewModel (especially if you expect more use cases) but it's not a _general_ answer you can get without more context.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I think you comments would make a nice answer :) I guess you're right, it depends on what I'm dealing with.

Comment: Tnx but they're really too short to be a decent useful answer. I imagine as use case a texbox which displays the number of characters left (as this textbox where we type comments). I, honestly, wouldn't go with ViewModel in this case (why bother who uses my control?!) and a `DependencyProperty` may work pretty well. Of course if things get more complex then I'd introduce a local private VM (setting `DataContext` of an inner container).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yeah, that sounds good. I've updated my question to put a bit more info on what I was (specifically) thinking when I asked it. Guess I'll follow up either with the DP or the private VM :)

Comment: @appayipyip in your edit you said the collection stays the same. If it's data does not change, I'm confused why would you need DP or Inotify interface.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry @EmersonCardoso, it did sound a bit confuse. I updated the quesion. What I meant was that the collection is not settable from outside, is it loaded with the app (by the control) and does not change. However, it can be filtered by the user, and I need a DP or INotify so that the UI knows that the collection changed when those filters change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit seems to change the perspective on things.  The bottom line is that if you want the UI to react to changes in your control, you have to tell it that things changed.  Based on a few years of WPF work, I've developed a few guidelines:

**Collections**

Use `ObservableCollection` as your type.  They notify the UI when values are added and removed.

Read-only properties can be simple properties:

```
public ObservableCollection Games { get; }
```

Otherwise use `DependencyProperty` and `ObservableCollection` together

```
public static DependencyProperty GamesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(...);

public ObservableCollection Games
{
    get { return GetValue(GamesProperty) as ObservableCollection; }
    set { SetValue(GamesProperty, value); }
}
```

**Properties on DependencyObjects (includes Controls)**

Never bind to a simple property.  There are old bugs in WPF that have not been fixed that cause memory leaks in this case.  Make everything a `DependencyProperty`.

`DependencyObjects` have their own set of rules, so any property used in the interaction really needs to be a `DependencyProperty`.  It's a pain in the butt, but it will save you headaches later.

**Properties on Models/ViewModels**

Anything that you intend to update on screen needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Those properties don't have the same memory leak as a simple property.

([More Information](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/))

Comment: So, in this case, I should not use a simple readonly (ObservableCollection) property (since it may cause memory leaks)?

Comment: You have a `DependencyObject` and your property is an `ObservableCollection`.  You'll be fine.  it's when you try to bind to a plain ol' C# object that doesn't have any notification features that you get memory leaks.

Answer (score 4):

A Control is the View part of M**V**VM. What you are updating in a View is dumb info (even if you have a complex control).

Generally, when you are creating a control is because:

- You need to render a lot of elements with little model info, it makes your main view to be bloated, and you cannot find the model's info you are using for that main view.
- You want to reuse some elements that happen to be together more than once. Perhaps is a title where is user's name in a place and category name in another place.

Thereby, your control must be agnostic about when model's property changes.
What you are looking for is the [DependencyProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property).

Conversely, the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) must be used in the ViewModel part of MV**VM** because it's the one who knows when:

- Business info (i. e. user's name) is changed in the Model.
- Dumb info (i.e. text) is changed in the View.

Comment: -1. Display logic should be handled in the View, not the VM. The incorrect assumption here is that all logic is business logic.

Comment: I agree with you on that, but I'm afraid I don't know how it contradicts what was said in the answer. Perhaps, I misunderstood the question somehow

Answer (score 1):

> What are the pros and cons of each approach? How should I proceid?

**1 - Make my Control implement INotifyPropertyChanged**

INotifyPropertyChanged is not a specific part of WPF. Therefore, if you want a simple publish/subscribe feature this interface is a good and standard way that .NET framework provides to do it.

**2 - Make Bar a readonly DependencyProperty**

In my understanding, you only want the `Bar` property to be "published" for the client (in your case the Control template) to update itself. Therefore, you don't need a DependencyProperty in this case, because you don't want to bind it to something else like a style, template or another runtime variable.

In this case, it would work, but it seems like a workaround (because you're implementing in the control) to accomplish your feature.

**3 - Another option**

I'm not sure if this is applicable because your example is too general, but I suggest a third option:

- Make your control as dumb as possible;
- Make `Foo` and `Bar` DependencyProperties;
- Create a ViewModel as a DataContext to your control
- Provide the values for `Foo` and `Bar` by making your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface